# SQL Server view getting data out of other database with different isolation level

Tags: sql-server, concurrency, blocked

We have two databases on the same SQL Server 2012 instance. Database `dbA_optimistic` has some tables with data records and `dbB_pessimistic` has some views which read data out of `dbA_optimistic` tables.

`dbA_optimistic` uses optimistic concurrency (READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON) and `dbB_pessimistic` (READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF) uses pessimistic concurrency. 
 [optimistic-concurrency](http://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2015/09/29/optimistic-concurrency-in-sql-server/)

Read-access to dbA does not acquire read locks and read access is not blocked during exclusive write access.

Read-access to dbB acquire read locks and read access is blocked while someone else holds an exclusive write access lock.

Easy game. :)

What happens if data is read using the views in dbB which read data out of dbA? Does `dbB_view` acquire read locks of `dbA_table`? Are this `dbB_view` accesses blocking dbA read/writeaccesses? (pessimistic concurrency in dbA even though dbA is set to optimistic concurrency?)

We had queries to dbB_views which blocked dbA_table sessions. sp_lock gave me some readlocks, seems wired.

Any idea?